# Canvas.js slows down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

**The problem:**

The problem I am encountering is that for each "JQuery event" click, the canvas.js diagram slows down proporsjonal to the click? I believe `$(document).ready(function(){` is responsible.
That is to say 10 clicks slows down the applciation 10 times. Keep in mind that I have five canvas.js diagrams (tables). [Canvas.js](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/)

Table1.js (The same code structure goes for the other diagrams, table2,table3 etc).

```
(function table1(){ 
 $(document).ready(function(){

            var dps = []; // data

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("table1",
        { 
          title:{
            text: "Exhaust Temperature"  
          data: [
          {        
            type: "spline",
            name: "Temp Cylinder 1",
            showInLegend: "true",
            legendText: "Temp Cylinder 1",
            dataPoints: dps1
          }
        });

        var xVal = 0; 
        var updateInterval = 50; 
        var dataLength = 50; 

    var updateChart = function (count) {
            count = count || 1;
            // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.
            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {    
                dps.push({
                    x: xVal,
                    y: EXTS[1]       
                });
                xVal++;
            }; 
            if (dps.length > dataLength )
            {
                dps.shift();             
            }
            chart.render();    
        };
        // generates first set of dataPoints
        updateChart(dataLength); 
        // update chart after specified time. 
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 
 });  
}());
```

This is JQuery event that is responsible for showing and hiding the diagrams, keep in mind that the user can only view one diagram at time.

```
    $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
         var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $('#table' + row).addClass('active'); 

         if (row == 1){
            $.getScript("table1.js", function(){}); 
            table1();
         } else if (row == 2) {
            $.getScript("table2.js", function(){}); 
            table2();
         } else if (row == 3) {
            $.getScript("table3.js", function(){}); 
            table3();  
         } 
    });
```

Comment: are you re-loading each javascript over and over again when someone already clicked on that row?

Comment: also, your intervals keep running and running. everytime a row is clicked a new interval will be created

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the problem of slow performance.. @Alex. Because before I load it second time, the first click displays the diagram in high performance.. Strange.